# Custom WP plugin based on Boilerplate plugin, shows a "1" at each public page

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, boilerplate

I am creating a custom WordPress plugin based on Boilerplate generator, and work fine. The only thing issue that to every frontend page that i display data from the plugin through a shortcode, at the end of the page, i get the number 1.

It seems that something produced that number but i searched all the files line by line and i cannot find what is producing it.

My hands up...i really cannot find what causes this 1 to be in each public page.

I suspect that it may is produced by

```
$this->loader->add_action( 'test-plugin', $plugin_public, 'display_front_page' );
add_shortcode( 'test-plugin', array( $plugin_public, 'display_front_page') );
```

This produces the shortcode [test-plugin] that it displayes the data from the function `display_front_page`

Any idea what causes that 1 to be displayed at the end of the page??